# Clojure - syntactic sugar to convert map entries to function params automatically?

Tags: function, dictionary, clojure

Suppose I have the following clojure function call:

```
(def mymap {:a1 1 :a2 2})

(defn my-adder [input-map]
    (let [a1 (:a1 input-map)
          a2 (:a2 input-map)]
      (+ a1 a2)))

(my-adder mymap)
```

What I'm looking for is for some way to make the my-adder function simpler by converting the map to params automatically - something like:

```
(defn my-adder [(magic-function input-map)]
  (+ a1 a2))
```

Can someone point me to what I'm missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I think you're looking for is destructuring.  Here's what you can do:

```
(def mymap {:a1 1 :a2 2})

(defn my-adder [{:keys [a1 a2]}]
      (+ a1 a2))

(my-adder mymap)
```

[You can learn more about it here](http://blog.jayfields.com/2010/07/clojure-destructuring.html).

Comment: :keys! Thats what I was looking for.

Comment: np, be aware there are many different ways you can destructure things.

Comment: @hawkeye I could, but I think the tutorial link I gave does a better job than I would.

Answer (score 2):

Use can use like bellow. It's called as Clojure: Destructuring. You can find more [here](http://blog.jayfields.com/2010/07/clojure-destructuring.html)

```
(defn my-adder [{a1 :a1 a2 :a2}]
      (+ a1 a2))
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answers showing destructuring, you could also use `apply` and `vals` if simply adding *all* values from your map together is fine for you:

```
(defn my-adder [m]
    (apply + (vals m)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use the fnk function in the [plumbing libary](https://github.com/Prismatic/plumbing#bring-on-defnk)

```
(use 'plumbing.core)

(defnk my-adder [a b] 
  (+ a b))
```